# Extract number from variable

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
$guid = 'http://www.test.com/?p=34';
```

How can I extract the value of get var `p` (34) from the string and have `$guid2 = '34'`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $vars);
$guid2 = $vars['p'];
```

Answer (score 3):

If 34 is the only number in the query string, you can also use

```
echo filter_var('http://www.test.com/?p=34', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); // 34
```

This will strip anything not a number from the URL string. However, this will fail the instant there is other numbers in the URL. The [solution offered by konforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237918/extract-number-from-variable/4237959#4237959) is the most reliable approach if you want to extract the value of the p param of the query string.

Answer (score 1):

A [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is probably the quickest way to get that variable, the code below will work if it is always a number.  Though [konforce's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237918/extract-number-from-variable/4237959#4237959) is the general way of getting that information from a URL, though it does a lot of work for that particular URL, which is very simple and can be dealt with simply if it unaltering.

```
$guid = 'http://www.test.com/?p=34';
$guid2 = preg_replace("/^.*[&?;]p=(\d+).*$/", "$1", $guid);
```

**Update**

Note that if the URLs can not be guaranteed to have the variable `p=<number>` in them, then you would need to use match instead, as preg_replace() would end up not matching and returning the whole string.

```
$guid = 'http://www.test.com/?p=34';
$matches = array();
if (preg_match("/^.*[&?;]p=(\d+).*$/", $guid, $matches)) {
    $guid2 = $matches[1];
} else {
    $guid2 = false;
}
```

Comment: this should probably include a check for `[?&;]` before the `p` to prevent `notp=12`. If `p` is the first argument, it will be `?p=`, if it is any but the first param it will be either `&p=` or, when the ampersands are encoded, `&amp;p=`.

Comment: @Gordon Good point, a case I neglected to take in to account.  I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is WordPress. On a single post page you can use get_the_ID() function (WP built-in, used in the loop only).

Answer (score 0):

```
$guid2 = $_GET['p']
```

For more security:

```
if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] != ''){
    $guid2 = $_GET['p'];
}
else{
    $guid2 = '1'; //Home page number
}
```